# Array Shenanigans in C

Tags: python, c, arrays

I had to make a unidimensional cellular automata and implement any of its rules in C.

Before going into C (not my forte to be honest), I coded it in python only using fixed arrays and only using for and while cycles (to make it straight forward to port). My problem is, in Python, I had this code:

```css
def bin(n):
    aux = 7
    bin = ''
    while aux>=0:
        if 2**aux <= n:            
            n-=2**aux
            bin += '1'
        else:
            bin+='0'
        aux-=1
    return list(bin)        

regla = bin(30)
print regla
ancho = 8
alto = 8
vector = []
valores_regla = ['111','110','101','100','011','010','001','000']

for i in range(ancho):
    vector.append('0')
vector[ancho/2]='1'

archivo = open('Imagen.pbm','w')
archivo.write('P1 '+str(ancho)+ ' ' + str(alto)+'\n')

aux = []
for y in range(alto):
    for x in range(len(vector)):
        i=x-1
        c=x
        d=x+1
        if x == 0:
            i=len(vector)-1
        if x == len(vector)-1:
            d=0
        for z in range(8):
            if vector[i]+vector[c]+vector[d] == valores_regla[z]:
                aux.append(regla[z])
    archivo.write( ''.join(aux) + '\n')
    vector = aux
    aux = []

print 'Terminado'
archivo.close()
```

Basically, I transformed my Integer to a 1-Byte String Binary, then assigned its rules to a an array (Valores_Regla, basically, counting to 0 to 7 in binary); then I proceeded to iterate over the vector, and if a match to a rule was found, append it to an empty array (Aux), write that array to a file , and then make my old vector=Aux.

This code works perfectly and generates .pbm images of the cellular automata over n=alto iterations. Now in C, I ported this code almost line by line, and it *almost* works.

My problem is when I try to "append" the new value to an array. I created an Aux array as well, filled with 0. Then I made the same cycle, checked the rule, and if it matches, then I assign the new value to the equivalent x position in the aux array. Until this point, it works perfectly:

```css
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char bufer[3];

bufer[0] =array[l];
bufer[1] = array[c];
bufer[2] = array[r];
bufer[3] = '\0';
```

The problem appears when I try to copy the contents of the Aux array into the Array array. It gets messed up.

I have double and triple checked the code and I can't see any errors. I am not even allocating memory, I am working with static arrays. I am clueless. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I just though about that, edited it and, nop, it still prints garbage

Comment: I see you are overrunning the 'bufer' array by storing a value in bufer[3] (fourth element, bufer was declared with only 3 elements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least one buffer overflow:

```
char bufer[3];
bufer[3] = '\0';
```

`bufer` needs to be of size 4.

Comment: I love you will all my soul. Almost 4 hours of debugging just because i was missing a +1 :C. At least my algorithm wasn't faulty. (PS: This is EXACTLY the reason why i hate C )

Comment: You may also want to use `strncmp` (or `memcmp`) instead of `strcmp` in the future.

Comment: I was originally using those but they were failing too, so i though they were the reason.

Comment: @NyxTheShield Compile with `-Wall` and/or `-Warray-bounds` in the future.

Comment: I always do (It's a requeriment here. For each warning we lose 20 points, and trust me, i don't want to get -40 points for unused variable warnings)

Answer (score 3):

`strncpy()` will stop at the first nul byte (value 0) or after `n` bytes (`ancho` in this case).  It probably hits the nul first.  Use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: How're you validating that it isn't working? Are you debugging?

Comment: I don't have a proper "debugger", but i am printing my Array, my Aux and my Matched Chars, and it prints garbage

Comment: As a side note, strncpy worked. memcpy does as well with the fix pointed above.